# MPMediaQuery addFilterPredicate removing all items from query from Smart Playlist

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes

I have a a section of code that is supposed to query the music library on an iOS device and return a subset of its contents. When this code is triggered for a playlist, I create an MPMediaQuery, then apply a series of filters using MPMediaPropertyPredicate. First, I filter for the type of content I want (music), then I remove all cloud content, and lastly, when browsing a playlist, I filter for items belonging to that playlist. This all works fine -- except for on smart playlists (and even then it works on some devices). Below is the code -- I can see that after the first two filters I still have a substantial list of items (10107), but after the final filter is applied, my query is reduced to 0 items when it is a smart playlist. I thought there was some kind of integer overflow going on, so I changed the "value" to be an NSDecimalNumber instead of NSNumber, and I always see the full playlist ID as an integer and never in scientific notation, but it did not fix the issue. Any idea what is going on?

```
- (MPMediaQuery*) queryFromObjectId:(NSString*)objectId
{

NSLog(@"INSIDE queryFromObjectId %@", objectId);

NSString *s;

MPMediaQuery* rv = [MPMediaQuery new];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:objectId];
NSString* type = url.host;

NSLog(@"URL: %@, type: %@", url, type);

NSArray* rootItem = [self.rootDict objectForKey:type];
if (rootItem != nil) {
    rv.groupingType = [rootItem[kRootIndexQuery] groupingType];
}

NSDictionary *parameters = [url nvt_queryDictionary];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate* pred;

// Filter proper media types
if (parameters[MPMediaItemPropertyPodcastPersistentID] || rv.groupingType == MPMediaGroupingPodcastTitle) {
    NSLog(@"Filtering for Podcast type");
    pred = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MPMediaTypePodcast] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Filtering for music/media type");
    pred = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MPMediaTypeMusic] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];
}
[rv addFilterPredicate:pred];

// Filter iCloud items
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 6) {
    NSLog(@"Filtering iCloud items");
    pred = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem];
    [rv addFilterPredicate:pred];
}

int index = 0;
for (NSString *key in parameters.allKeys) {

    NSLog(@"Inside for loop, KEY: %@, index: %d", key, index);
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *pred;

    if ([key isEqualToString:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID] || [key isEqualToString:MPMediaItemPropertyPodcastPersistentID]) {
        NSLog(@"IF inside FOR");
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
//            NSNumber *value = [formatter numberFromString:parameters[key]];
        NSDecimalNumber *value = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:parameters[key]];
        pred = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:value forProperty:key];
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"ELSE inside FOR");
        id value = parameters[key];
        pred = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:value forProperty:key];
    }

    s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BEFORE FILTER items:%u",  rv.items.count];
    NSLog(s);

    s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Predicate: value: %@, key: %@", pred.value, pred.property];
    NSLog(s);

    [rv addFilterPredicate:pred];

    s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AFTER FILTER items:%u",  rv.items.count];
    NSLog(s);

    index++;
}

return rv;
}
```

In the logs I see:

```
2017-03-21 11:09:26.090316 T[1978:1214332] INSIDE queryFromObjectId //Tracks?playlistPersistentID=9690568479441451477
2017-03-21 11:09:26.090549 T[1978:1214332] URL: //Tracks?playlistPersistentID=9690568479441451477, type: Tracks
2017-03-21 11:09:26.090690 T[1978:1214332] Filtering for music/media type
2017-03-21 11:09:26.090846 T[1978:1214332] Filtering iCloud items
2017-03-21 11:09:26.090967 T[1978:1214332] Inside for loop, KEY: playlistPersistentID, index: 0
2017-03-21 11:09:26.091017 T[1978:1214332] IF inside FOR
2017-03-21 11:09:26.091200 T[1978:1214332] BEFORE FILTER items:10107
2017-03-21 11:09:26.091298 T[1978:1214332] Predicate: value: 9690568479441451477, key: playlistPersistentID
2017-03-21 11:09:26.091765 T[1978:1214332] AFTER FILTER items:0
```

This all works perfectly for non-smart playlists.

Additionally, If I remove the iCloud filtering part -- which seems to be doing nothing -- all the smart playlists load... but the load the same content: the content of the smart playlist with the lowest numbered ID. Here are the names and IDs of the playlists I'm testing with:

Top500MostPlayed    "9690568479441451477"

RecentlyPlayed  "9690568479441451478"

RecentlyAdded   "9690568479441451479"

5stars  "9690568479441451476"

When the iCloud filtering is removed, all smart playlists load the content of the playlist "5Stars".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

The ID needed to be an unsigned long to hold that large of a number:

```
        unsigned long long valueLong = strtoull([parameters[key] UTF8String], NULL, 0);
        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:valueLong];
        pred = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:value forProperty:key];
```